# Python ProcessPoolExecutor with QueueHandler

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, queue

I want to log to a single file in a multiple process environment. I can get the [sample code](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) work from python logging cookbook. But when I replace with the ProcessPoolExecutor it's not working.

```
#    workers = []
#    for i in range(4):
#        worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process,
#                                         args=(queue, worker_configurer))
#        workers.append(worker)
#        worker.start()
#    for w in workers:
#        w.join()

import concurrent.futures
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for i in range(4):
        executor.submit(worker_process, queue, worker_configurer)
        print(f'submit worker {i}')
```

Comment: how *it's not working* ?

Comment: i see the 4 "submit" in the console, but then it seems hang, and no log entries in the log file/console. Not sure it's related to Queue in the ProcessPoolExecutor or not.

Comment: can you share your `worker_process` definition?

Comment: worker_process same as in the link. As Vinay replied, change to Manager().Queue solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change slightly the way the queue is created in the recipe. Instead of

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)
```

do

```
queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(-1)
```

and it should then work. On my system:

```
Worker started: ForkProcess-3
Worker started: ForkProcess-4
Worker started: ForkProcess-5
Worker started: ForkProcess-6
Worker finished: ForkProcess-5
Worker finished: ForkProcess-4
Worker finished: ForkProcess-6
Worker finished: ForkProcess-3
```

**Update:** I've updated the cookbook recipe in the documentation to describe the usage of `concurrent.futures`. The update should show up once the documentation is rebuilt.